# SignOut in PHP website

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am trying to log out from a PHP website by using the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
   $_SESSION=array();
   if($_COOKIE[session_name()])

   {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
   }
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
}

?>
```

The page gets redirected to Login page but when I click back button of browser, I am able to see the previous page. Please suggest a comprehensive solution that can resolve this, since on various posts, I am not able to find a solution where User can completely logout the php website. (if possible, without using javascript). I want to be on the login page itself even when back button is pressed after logout.

Comment: What happens when you hit back and then hit refresh?

Comment: pressing back doesn´t reload the site, maybe it is still in the cache of the browser, refresh to check what happend and if it worked.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. When I am doing logout and backbutton(refresh)...it is showing me error at the position (of the previous page) where session variable is used and the remaining page which is not using any session variable to display, it is showing as is..

Comment: What is the code of the previous page? Are you validating if there is some kind of session variable loaded?

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start(); 
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); 
header ('location:login.php?message=logout');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code and it should help prevent caching.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```

Comment: Even this don't work

<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
   $_SESSION=array();
   if($_COOKIE[session_name()])

   {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
   }
session_destroy();
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Location: login.php');
}

?>

Comment: What browser are you trying it in?

Comment: Also when you go back and hit refresh, does it show you are logged in or out?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome.

When I am doing logout and backbutton(refresh)...it is showing me error at the position (of the previous page) where session variable is used and the remaining page which is not using any session variable to display, it is showing as is...

Comment: Does your session have a variable? If not Try using `session_unset();` instead of `session_destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

Add a statement at the beginning of your "page", which checks for the session credentials, and if they do not exist, it redirects the user to the login page, else, it loads the page.

To actually write the conditional block for you, I would need  the actual php, but something along the lines of...

If Session is False

Scripting to redirect browser to Login Page

Else

Load Page

End If

Answer (score 0):

If your code uses AJAX to log out, then using `session_start()` starts a brand new session instead of continuing the session you were using.

If you use AJAX, do the following when the user logs in:

```
#start a new session
session_start();
#save the session id into a cookie
setcookie('SESSID', session_id(), 0, '/');
```

Now that your session is saved, in order to log out, try this code:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['SESSID']))
{
    #retrieve the previous session id
    session_id($_COOKIE['SESSID']);
    session_start();

    #destroy the session
    session_destroy();
    setcookie('SESSID', NULL, time() - 3600, '/');
}
```